# Any good sources on advaced/special rasterization algorithms and techniques and theory behind them?

Tags: vector-graphics, rasterizer

I spent quite some time looking for books on rasterization of vector graphics and related challenges. The best I found is "Raster Tragedy in Low Resolution",which is old and focused on fonts. There are assorted papers on new renderer here and there, but nothing comprehensive.

Is ththere something good I missed?

Comment: What are "advanced/special" rasterization algorithms? How are they different from the normal kind of rasterization?

Comment: The ones specialized for correcting or playing around limitations of displays (anti aliasing measures, various small shape/position adjustments to avoid strat pixel defects and so on)

Comment: Requests for books, papers, etc. are considered off-topic here. If you have a specific question about the topic, feel free to ask that, though.

Comment: *"The ones specialized for correcting or playing around limitations of display"* Do you mean just like font-hinting tricks, or are you interested in filtering/reconstruction/coping with Nyquist limits/human visual systems?

Comment: @Simon_f mostly the second

Comment: In that case, perhaps Andrew Glassner's "Principles of Digital Image Synthesis" *might* be useful. You may want to borrow from a library, though, as it comes in two large volumes and I have a feeling that the 1st volume might be the more relevant for this. Unfortunately, my copy "walked off" some time ago and I've not seen it since, so I can't check. :-(

Answer (score 1):

One rasterization method I like is Haar wavelet rasterization:

http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/wavelet_rasterization.pdf

It can render polygons and Bezier curve shape and good for different resolution. I not see this algorithm in computer graphics books.

Answer (score 1):

Quake subdivision rasterization comes to mind. https://www.bluesnews.com/abrash/chap69.shtml , under ”An idea that did work”.